# Can I make a Smart Card using a flash drive?

Tags: mac, usb, security, usb-flash-drive, smartcard

I want to require a user to plug in a flash drive before letting them authenticate with his/her password.

Are there any solutions that work well for laptops, preferably Macs?

I'm not looking for a Smart Card, I want something more portable and off the shelf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Superuser!

The company I worked for used a solution by  Rohos, here's a link to their website:
http://www.rohos.com/products/rohos-logon-key-for-mac/

They offer flash drive login authentication for both Windows and Mac operating system. It comes with Two-factor authentication with PIN code which makes our system more secure.

I hope my answer helped, please ask if you have additional questions.